# Latex MacTex GnuPlot Tickz Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, mac

Gnuplot 5.0 is installed. If i type Gnuplot in Terminal, everything is fine.
Tex Live Utility tells me there's no updates available.

What do i need to do to fix this error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/gnuplot' and I
>   am going t o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: Can you show the full code ? This looks like you are providing the key in the wrong place.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It also seems to interact badly with BibTex.